# Shiny withSpinner hide or toggle

Tags: r, shiny, toggle, hide

I am trying to hide the spinner at the beginning when no choice has been made yet.
This is a simple example of what I have achieved so far.

```
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "something",
            label = "Select something:",
            choices = c('','None', 'All', 'Some'),
            selected = ''),
  withSpinner(textOutput(outputId = "text")  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    toggle(id = 'text', condition = F)

    if(nchar(input$something) > 0 ){
      toggle(id = 'text', condition = T)
      Sys.sleep(1)
      output$text <- renderText(paste("You chose ",input$something))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The spinners appear correctly when the choice is changed. Unfortunately, at the beginning the toggle seems to work only on the text, not on the spinner itself. 
I also tried with
`withSpinner(textOutput(outputId = "text") , id = 'myspin' )` in the UI and `toggle(id = 'myspin', condition = F)` in the server, but no luck yet. `hide(id = 'text')` seems to have no effect either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the container at the start and then enable it again

```
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput(inputId = "something",
                label = "Select something:",
                choices = c('','None', 'All', 'Some'),
                selected = ''),
    hidden(div(id = 'test', withSpinner(textOutput(outputId = "text"))))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observe({
        toggle(id = 'text', condition = FALSE)
        
        if(nchar(input$something) > 0 ){
            show('test')
            toggle(id = 'text', condition = TRUE)
            Sys.sleep(1)
            output$text <- renderText(paste("You chose ", input$something))
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```